# On the (Pre-)History of Sheaf Theory

Tags: terminology, math-history, sheaf-theory, philosophy, sheaf-cohomology

In the [wikipedia page on sheaf theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sheaf_(mathematics)#History) I found the following statement which somehow puzzled me:

> some of the facets of sheaf theory can also be traced back as far as Leibniz.

Could anyone explain that further? Which ideas where contained in Leibniz which are part (or at least a seed) of sheaf theory? Bibiographic reference to passages from Leibniz would be welcome, as well as some conceptual clarification of the point being made.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The full context of that quote (with an irrelevant parenthetical omitted) is "It was later discovered that the logic in categories of sheaves is intuitionistic logic [...]. This shows that some of the facets of sheaf theory can also be traced back as far as Leibniz."  So presumably they are just saying that intuitionistic logic can in some way be traced back to Leibniz.

Comment: This question would possibly be better at home at [hsm.se]